# Spotlight not indexing secondary drive

Tags: spotlight, indexing

I have two drives on my MacBook Pro. One is a SSD with the root (/) partition, and the other is a hard drive with a home directory partition (/Users). Both partitions are HFS+ format.

When I make a search using Spotlight, nothing on the /Users partition is searchable, since it is not indexed.

Trying to use mdutil to start indexing the drive does not work:

```
## Attempt to enable indexing and flush any existing index
$ mdutil -i on -E /Users
/Users:
        Indexing and searching disabled.

## Attempting the same as above to all volumes
$ mdutil -i on -E -a
/:
        Indexing enabled. 
/Users:
        Indexing and searching disabled.
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is due to having the `nobrowse` mount option set for the affected partition. Removing this option for the partition's /etc/fstab line fixes this issue.

Comment: You did not name this in the question, did you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **System settings**
2. Click **Spotlight**
3. Click **Privacy**
4. Open a finder window and navigate to /Volumes
5. Drag the harddrive to the available space as you can see on image below
6. Click the **-** to remove the disk and it will start indexing again

[image]

Comment: I tried adding and removing the root partition and the /Users partition, and that did not work.